# Disable D3 zoomed map scaling to original size on click

Tags: d3.js, click, zooming

Im using zoom and pan on a map in d3 v4. When the map is zoomed in and a single click is made, the map reverts back to its original size. How can this be stopped? Id like the map to remain in any zoom state even on click.

Thanks

Comment: Zooming out on click is not the default functionality of d3 zoom. Please consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just comment out the the .on("click" ...) function. WIthout seeing a code we cannot help you more.